# How to write user input (taken from Tkinter's Entry) in newly created file

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I wanted to get user input from user using Tkinter's Entry something like this

```
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()
label = Label(top, text="Enter your bio")
entry = Entry(top, bd = 2)
 
def create_new():
   new_file = open('file.txt', 'w+')
   user_input = str(entry) # I ALSO TRIED WITHOUT str()
   new_file.write(user_input) #still doesn't work

button = Button(top, text = "SAVE", fg ="red", command=create_new) 

label.pack()
entry.pack()
button.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

When I add my info in the field and hit *SAVE*, it does create a new file.txt but it doesn't write my info into the file.txt

file.txt only has some numbers like these

> .22775808
>
> .22710272
>
> .22382592

etc...

Any ideas on how can I fix this? Also what do these numbers mean and why are they here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't writing the *contents* of the Entry, you're writing *the Entry itself* - which from Python's point of view is just the randomly-generated name of the actual widget which lives in the embedded Tcl/Tk interpreter.  Use `entry.get()` for the actual contents.

You're also forgetting to close the file after you write to it, so anything you do manage to write may not show up immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I tried entry.get() and it worked. also yeah i forgot to close the file so thanks again for reminding me ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()
label = Label(top, text="Enter your bio")

entry = Entry(top, bd = 2)

def create_new():
   new_file = open('file.txt', 'w+')
   user_input = (entry).get() # I ALSO TRIED WITHOUT str()
   new_file.write(user_input) #still doesn't work

button = Button(top, text = "SAVE", fg ="red", command=create_new) 

label.pack()
entry.pack()
button.pack()`enter code here`
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just try this one, may be it will help you.